# Is it possible to respond messege with status code before sending json response from a server

Tags: node.js, http

after getting request from a client I want to response the status code with a message .
After Analysing the received data I want to response Json data .
How it could be done???

Comment: are you wanting this to be asynchronous?

Comment: asynchronous or  synchronous anyway just want it to work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
res.status('status_code').send('data');
```

Like,

```
res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
```